# PHP Switch want to break html inside code

Tags: php, html, session, switch-statement, uikit

I'm using iukit and PHP session.

In my site, I have 3 people(roles): admin, operator and partner.

When I log in with one of these and I change to another page, I want to go back if possible.

But I need to change one navigator link.

So I tried to make php switch like this:

First I tried a simple switch with

```
echo '<li ..>foo</li>';
```

but I've seen the documentation and this is what I've found (much better I think).

I tried to put break instead of exit.

```php
<?php switch($_SESSION['person_role']): ?>
<?php case 'admin': ?>
<li class="uk-margin-left uk-margin-right"><a href="admin.html">Admin</a></li>
<?php exit;?>
<?php case 'operator': ?>
<li class="uk-margin-left uk-margin-right"><a href="operator.html">Operator</a></li>
<?php exit;?>
<?php case 'partner': ?>
<li class="uk-margin-left uk-margin-right"><a href="partner.html">Partner</a></li>
<?php exit;?>
<?php default: ?>
nothing
<?php endswitch;; ?>
```

The result is that all of the link are avaiable for every person.
Why the switch cannot break the code?

Comment: You shouldn't use `exit;` since that will end the entire script, you won't be able to output `</ul></body></html>`.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add in curly brackets: <code>switch() { ... }</code>

Comment: Is PHP being executed?  The file is `.php`?  Add `<?php phpinfo() ?>` to the top, does it display?

Comment: @JasonKLai He's using the alternative syntax with `:` instead of `{}`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Thanks AbraCadaver, I missed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a switch case here:

```
$roles = array(
    'admin' => 'Admin',
    'operator' => 'Operator',
    'partner' => 'Partner'
);

if (array_key_exists($_SESSION['person_role'], $roles)) {
    echo '<li class="uk-margin-left uk-margin-right"><a href="' . $_SESSION['person_role'] . '.html">' . $roles[$_SESSION['person_role']] . '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Hi parsonsbot your code is brilliant! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that you can run: https://3v4l.org/iQqqn

Instead of writing `PHP` in and out of `HTML` code, why not just evaluate with the `switch/case`, set variables, and `echo` them out in 1 line of `HTML` code instead of repeating it? Or, if you're sanitizing your `$_SESSION` data, you could just `echo` that out in the `HTML` like in the example:

```php
<?php
$_SESSION['person_role'] = 'admin';  // set for testing demo

// Either do your switch case and set variables...
$page = "default";
$role = "default";

// You technically don't even need the variables, but this example 
// shows that based on the case, if you need to use a different name
// for role/page this is where you would do so...
switch($_SESSION['person_role']) {
    case 'admin':
        $page = $role = "admin";
    break;
    case 'operator': 
        $page = $role = "operator";
    break;
    case 'partner':
        $page = $role = "partner";
    break;
}
?>
  Example W/ Switch Case..
  <ul>
    <li class="uk-margin-left uk-margin-right">
      <a href="<?php echo $page; ?>.html">
        <?php echo ucwords($role); ?>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Alternatively

```
<?php
// Just use $_SESSION data (assuming sanitized) in the HTML...
$_SESSION['person_role'] = 'operator';  // set for testing demo
?>
    Example just using $_SESSION data..
    <ul>
      <li class="uk-margin-left uk-margin-right">
        <a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['person_role']; ?>.html">
          <?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['person_role']); ?>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: It's two separate examples of how this could be done. Open and closing PHP tags and repeating the same HTML doesn't seem like good practice when you can just set variables and echo them once..

Comment: @Qirel thanks for the edit, sorry didn't break that out into 2 blocks to begin with!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$roles = array("admin", "operator", "partner");
$current_role = $_SESSION['person_role'];
if(in_array($current_role, $roles)) {
   echo '<li class="uk-margin-left uk-margin-right"><a href="'.$current_role.'\.html">'.ucfirst($current_role).'</a>
     </li>';
} else {
  echo 'No role in session';
}
?>
```